# Manually parsing geojson into a dataframe

Tags: r, geojson, tidyr, tibble

I would like to work step by step to convert a `.geojson` into a tibble (or dataframe).

Here's a minimalistic geojson example which I stored in a file called `test.geojson` (note that the `geometry` field is `null` but this does not matter here) :

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "VAR_1": 31,"VAR_2": "abc","VAR_3": 255 }, "geometry" : null },
    { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "VAR_1": 23,"VAR_2": "def","VAR_3": 876 }, "geometry" : null }
    ]}
```

Desired result (here assuming that `geometry` is filled with two coordinates instead of being `null`)

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  VAR_1 VAR_2 VAR_3 geometry
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <list>
1    31 abc     255 <dbl [2]>
2    23 def     876 <dbl [2]>
```

I'd partiularly like a `{tidyverse}` based solution. What I've been trying for now is iterate through each `features` to try and build a dataframe but I can't find a way to nicely add the `geometry` field :

```
# Read geojson
js <- jsonlite::read_json("test.geojson") 

# Iterate through each features ... 
map_dfr(1:length(js$features), .f = function(i){
  
  df <- js$features[[i]]$properties # this works but only importing VAR_1, VAR_2, VAR_3
 
  df |> mutate(geometry = js$features[[i]]$geometry) # this does not work
  
})
```

Note : One could use `{geojsonsf}` to import this directly as `sf` object with `sf <- geojsonsf::geojson_sf("test.geojson")` but I want to do it step by step, ending up on a tibble and understanding what I'm doing.

Thanks a lot for helping !

Comment: just to be clear, you're wanting to do this manually - if a package can do this for you, you don't want it?

Comment: I want to understand how to deal with different json structures. Using a function designed for a specific structure helps in that case, but it doesn't help me to understand how the json is modified to a tibble. Thanks for your nice answer !

Comment: re: understand how the json is modified to a tibble- I suppose if you want to learn how fromJSON works, you can read the source code

Comment: creating a custom thing is probably a lot of work and not necessary, at least for the example you gave

Comment: Indeed it's not necessary for my example. However I had to deal with complex json, many `hoist()`, `unnest()` etc. calls and this raised my curiosity to understand better this type of format. If I don't understand, I don't remember :-(

Comment: ah okay! In that case, playing around with it a bit more might be useful. `hoist()` and `unnest()` are great for nested columns, however, you'd first have to turn it into a dataframe

Comment: JSON isn't a million miles away from a Python dict, or a named list in R. You could create a parser which goes through the raw string, parsing the names and values, and turn it into a named list. Then `hoist` and `unnest` would come in handy

Comment: Thanks, will try that. I feel like there are many packages doing similar but not exactly similar stuff with JSON files, and that's a bit confusing. Will read some doc !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the data is something like this:

```
x <- '{"type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "VAR_1": 31,"VAR_2": "abc","VAR_3": 255 }, "geometry" : [-74.0060, 40.7128]},
    { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "VAR_1": 23,"VAR_2": "def","VAR_3": 876 }, "geometry" : [-74.0060, 40.7128]}
    ]}'
```

You can do this:

```
library(tidyverse)

jsonlite::fromJSON(x)$features |>
  as_tibble() |>
  select(properties, geometry) |>
  unnest(properties)

# Output:
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  VAR_1 VAR_2 VAR_3 geometry 
  <int> <chr> <int> <list>   
1    31 abc     255 <dbl [2]>
2    23 def     876 <dbl [2]>
```